# can I check with Valgrind or Gdb if another pointer holds the same address?

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

Im doing tests to a program I wrote for school and I got a **segmentation fault** with this msg

```
double free or corruption (out)
```

after I try to free an adress.

So I guess I had released this address before , So my question is - can valgrind/gdb tell me if an address is being pointed out by two different pointers ? or  given an address Can they tell me how many pointers point to it?

Comment: Not necessarily it's double free or **corruption**, please post the code if you want help.

Comment: @iharob umm its kind of a big program to post here, but lets say it is double free , is there a way to do what I asked

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind will tell you where you tried to dealocate the block for the second time and where you initially deallocated it:

```
==21347== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==21347==    at 0x4C2A37C: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21347==    by 0x4005CA: main (test.c:7)
==21347==  Address 0x51dc040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,000 free'd
==21347==    at 0x4C2A37C: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21347==    by 0x4005BE: main (test.c:6)
```

Code that generate this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char * x = malloc(1000);
    free(x);
    free(x);
}
```